# Azure Service Bus, could I use event-driven message programming in Azure Java SDK?

Tags: azure, servicebus

The event-driven message programming feature is supported in .NET Azure SDK. But it seems it's not supported in Azure Java SDK. With this feature, I don't need to poll for message in a Service Bus Queue or Subscription. If new messages comes, it will invoke call back function to handle this message. So if I want to use this event-driven when I use Azure Java SDK, how can I do it? Is there any way I can do it similar?

Comment: you shall not duplicate yourself. Rather refine your existing question! Questions do allow to be edited.

Comment: Sorry astaykov. Could you help me answer this question? if I want to use Azure Java SDK, how can I do it?